# Microsoft Word 2010 Table- Single Page

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

Trying to keep a table on one page- tried "keep lines together" and "keep with next". Neither works- what am I doing wrong? Should I select the text of the table or the whole table? Tried both, neither worked.

Comment: Can you describe how the feature is "not working". What happens when your table is positioned over a page break? Does the whole table move to the next page?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried "Page break before"? If not, put your cursor in the first cell of the table, select the "Paragraph" dialogue box, go to the "Line and Page Breaks" tab and select "Page break before".

Answer (score 0):

You may also have to select the table, right-click and select Table Properties, click the Row tab and uncheck "Allow row to break across pages"